# unindex old website (old domain name) from google

Tags: wordpress, seo

I did a domain name migration for a wordpress site, in fact I moved from **« [www.site.fr](http://www.site.fr) »** to **« [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) »** (this is not the real url this is just to give an example)
My problem is that when I use the « site: [www.site.fr](http://www.site.fr) » command on the google chrome browser it shows me results from the old domain name.
What must be done to remove all links from the old site? knowing that there was a DNS redirection that was made (the .fr domain points to the .com)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Search engeines will eventually update, and your old domain will be forgotten - but if you care about SEO, and assuming you still own the old domain (site.fr), I think it would be best to tell search engines that the site has permanently moved (301 Redirect) to a new domain.

A common way of implementing redirects is through an `.htaccess` file, which runs on servers. To redirect an entire domain to a new site, write this in `.htaccess` and put it on your old domain:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

(replace example.com with your new domain!) This will 301 redirect every page on your old site to the corresponding URL on the target domain.